# Http post server request via android application display submit button (Login) from login.php page

Tags: java, php, android, http, androidhttpclient

I have a php file setup with login and authentication via server. I am trying to do POST HTTP connection to that login.php file and verify login authentication. I might sound quite naive in asking question, please let me know if I have to clarify more.

```
package com.myproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Conversations;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.MalformedJsonException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private String mTitle = "Write.My.Action";
    private static final String LOGTAG = "tag";
    public EditText username, password;
    private Button login, register; 
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.login:
            if((username.getText().toString().length() < 1) || (password.getText().toString().length() < 1)){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter username and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            }
        case R.id.register:
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        boolean failure = false;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Attempting to Login...");
            mDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                String input_username = username.getText().toString();
                String input_password = password.getText().toString();
                //Log.i(LOGTAG, "Username is "+ input_username);


                String link = "http://psmovers.com.au/login.php";

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(input_username, "UTF-8");
                data+="&" +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(input_password, "UTF-8");
                //Log.i(LOGTAG, "Data is "+ data);
                URL url = new URL(link);

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();


                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
//              Log.i(LOGTAG, "Wr value is " + wr);
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null; 
                //Read server response

                while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print("The result after while loop: " + sb.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Exception:" + e.toString());
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mDialog.setTitle("Login Success");
            mDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result is :" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I have INTERNET permission setup in Manifest file, It is also reading the URL, successfully getting text input from devise, also I am able to open the above URL link independently on my tablet..

```
System.out.print("The result after while loop: " + sb.toString());
```

The output in Logcat is: The result after the while loop : `<h1>Login</h1>`

even the toast message onPostexeecute method id

Result is : `<h1>Login</h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break;` in while loop is not necessary.

```
while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
  sb.append(line + "\n");
  // break;
}
```

Comment: Ya, I just deleted break. Its not helping. The result onPostExecute() is null.

Comment: return sb.toString() is also necessary.

Comment: hi, I had return sb.toString(); as well. But I changed to System.out.print () to test on my logcat. Now, I am getting something on the result though after removing break and retuning sb.toString();I believe removing break solved my problem so I accepted the answer. Thank you for your time ;)